# Tesseract OCR line breaks on command line

Tags: tesseract

I am using tesseract.exe in Windows 7 by command line and while scanning image for OCR, I get output in continuous lines. I want it in the word wrap exactly the way it is in image. Is there a command line argument for such variations? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Tesseract puts just line feeds at the end of a line instead of carriage returns + line feeds as expected by Windows' Notepad. An easy workaround is to output the results to stdout and redirect this output into a file:

```
tesseract.exe eurotext.tif - > result.txt
```

instead of

```
tesseract.exe eurotext.tif result
```

Comment: tried it.
 it creates 2 files. -.txt with same data in it i.e. all in single line and result.txt which is an empty file

Comment: - works for me with version 3.05. You could also try stdout instead of -. Alternatively you can convert LF to CR+LF in Windows by `TYPE result.txt | FIND "" /V >result1.txt`.